# Low Search not displaying all results

Tags: low-search

I'm using Low Search on my site and it's not displaying all results. I've rebuilt the index and lexicon. I'm testing this with one product. If I go to the products page I see product but if I try and search for it, no result for the title. Here is the code for the results page.

```
{exp:low_search:results
                    query="{segment_3}"
                    channel="products"
                    limit="15"
                    name="range:tags"
                    dynamic="off" 
                    orderby="release_date" 
                    sort="desc"
                }

                  {if count == 1}
                    <p>
                    Searched for <strong>{low_search_keywords}</strong>.
                    Search results: <strong>{absolute_results}</strong>
                    </p>
            {/if}

                {if count==1}<ul class="thumbnails">{/if}
                    {switch="<div class='row'>||"}
                    <li class="span3">                      

                <div class="thumbnail">
                    {if product_thumbnail}
                            <a class='' href="{entry_id_path='{template_group}/product_detail'}"><img src="{product_thumbnail}" /></a>
                    {if:else}
                    <a class='' href="{entry_id_path='{template_group}/product_detail'}"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt=""></a>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>{title}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
                {switch="||</div>"}
                    {if count==total_results}</ul><!-- end row -->{/if}
                    {paginate}
                        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>


                     {if previous_page}
        <a href="{auto_path}">Previous Page</a> &nbsp;
    {/if}
    {if next_page}
        <a href="{auto_path}">Next Page</a>
    {/if}
                    {/paginate}

                    {if no_results}
                        <p>Sorry, nothing found.</p>
                    {/if}
                {/exp:low_search:results}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Low Search is giving no or not all results, check the following things:

#### Native default parameter values negating search results

The Results tag extends the [native channel:entries tag](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html), so default filtering is in place:

- `status` will be limited to `open` only;
- `show_future_entries` will be set to `no`;
- `show_expired` will be set to `no`.

In 9 out of 10 cases, the [status](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#status) is not explicitly given, so only open entries are shown.

#### Searchable fields are not weighted

For [Keyword](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords) searches, the keywords must be present in the index. For words to be present in the index, the fields must have **weight of at least 1**. In order to give fields weight, create a [collection](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/collections#weight) for it. In order for a field to show up in the collection details, it must be marked as Searchable in the field settings.

#### Very small amount of data in the index

The way keyword searches work (or to be more precise, MySQL full-text searches), means keywords shouldn't be "common". They are considered common if they appear in more than half of the index. Usually, this isn't a problem at all. However, when you're just setting up a site, and you have very few entries indexed with the same keywords, it's possible those keywords are considered common by MySQL, and will therefore not match a search query. Having more data/entries will solve the problem.

#### Other trouble shooting tips

Low Search uses the [Template Debugger](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html#display-template-debugging) extensively. If you're getting unexpected results, turn it on, and look up any lines that mention Low Search or low_search. That should give you some more insight as to what is going on.